# I can't move my image using the css selectors?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to move the icons or images to the center of the css circles which I'm using as background (which I called blocks). They appear at the corner of the circle, so I try to position it to the center. There seems to be something wrong with my selector code, or something else maybe. It isn't changing the position of the icons whether I try margin or anything.

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: Bahnschrift;
  font-size: 13;
}

h1,h2,h3{margin: auto; text-align:center;}

.wrap {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 108px;
  background-color: #001e22;
}

header .wrap > img {
  margin-top: 17px;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

li {
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 48px;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.banner > img {
width: 100%;
}

.wrap .block-row {
background: white;

}

.wrap #block1{
margin-left:80px;
margin-right:80px;
margin-top:80px;
width:100px; 
height:100px;
background-color:#2fcbe0;
border-radius:100px;
display:inline-block;
}

.wrap #block2{
margin-left:80px;
margin-right:80px;
margin-top:80px;
width:100px; 
height:100px;
background-color:#2fcbe0;
border-radius:100px;
display:inline-block;

}

.wrap #block3{
margin-top:80px;
margin-left:80px;
margin-right:80px;
width:100px; 
height:100px;
background-color:#2fcbe0;
border-radius:100px;
display:inline-block;
}

.wrap #block4{
margin-top:80px;
margin-left:80px;
margin-right:80px;
width:100px; 
height:100px;
background-color:#2fcbe0;
border-radius:100px;
display:inline-block;
}


h1{margin-top:80px; font-size:48px;}

.wrap #block1,
.wrap #block2,
.wrap #block3,
.wrap #block4 {
    position: relative; 

    
}
.wrap #block1 span,
.wrap #block2 span,
.wrap #block3 span,
.wrap #block4 span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;     
    font-size: 26px;
}

.wrap #block1 p,
.wrap #block2 p,
.wrap #block3 p,
.wrap #block4 p{ 
position: absolute;
top:150px;
width:230px;
text-align:center;
left:-60px;
font-size:15px;
}

.wrap #block1 span{
left:10px;}

.wrap #block2 span,
.wrap #block3 span,
.wrap #block4 span {     
    left:-10px;

.block-row .wrap > img{position:relative; top:-30px;}
```

```html
<body>
<header>
  <div class="wrap">
    <img src="logo.png" alt="logo">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">CONTACT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="">SOFTWARE USED</a></li>
        <li><a href="">PROJECT</a></li>
        <li><a href="">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<section class="banner">
  <img src="building.png" alt="banner">
</section>

<h1>SOME ICONS</h1>
<section class="block-row">

<div class="wrap">
<div id="block1"> <img src="pers.png"><span> ABOUT </span> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. </p> </div>
<div id="block2"><img src="shield.png"> <span> COMPANY </span> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. </p></div>
<div id="block3"> <img src="cog.png"><span> SERVICES </span> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. </p></div>
<div id="block4"><img src="globe.png"><span> CONTACT </span>  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. </p></div>
</div>

</section>

</body>
```

Comment: Did you try `text-align: center`?

Comment: @ManojKumar yes

Answer (score 0):

Give margin to the image to position it. Try the code below.

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: Bahnschrift;
  font-size: 13;
}

h1,h2,h3{margin: auto; text-align:center;}

.wrap {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 108px;
  background-color: #001e22;
}

header .wrap > img {
  margin-top: 17px;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

li {
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 48px;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.banner > img {
width: 100%;
}

.wrap .block-row {
background: white;

}

.wrap #block1{
margin-left:80px;
margin-right:80px;
margin-top:80px;
width:100px; 
height:100px;
background-color:#2fcbe0;
border-radius:100px;
display:inline-block;
}

.wrap #block2{
margin-left:80px;
margin-right:80px;
margin-top:80px;
width:100px; 
height:100px;
background-color:#2fcbe0;
border-radius:100px;
display:inline-block;

}

.wrap #block3{
margin-top:80px;
margin-left:80px;
margin-right:80px;
width:100px; 
height:100px;
background-color:#2fcbe0;
border-radius:100px;
display:inline-block;
}

.wrap #block4{
margin-top:80px;
margin-left:80px;
margin-right:80px;
width:100px; 
height:100px;
background-color:#2fcbe0;
border-radius:100px;
display:inline-block;
}


h1{margin-top:80px; font-size:48px;}

.wrap #block1,
.wrap #block2,
.wrap #block3,
.wrap #block4 {
    position: relative; 

    
}
.wrap #block1 span,
.wrap #block2 span,
.wrap #block3 span,
.wrap #block4 span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;     
    font-size: 26px;
}


.wrap #block1 img,
.wrap #block2 img,
.wrap #block3 img,
.wrap #block4 img {
  margin:40px;
}

.wrap #block1 p,
.wrap #block2 p,
.wrap #block3 p,
.wrap #block4 p{ 
position: absolute;
top:150px;
width:230px;
text-align:center;
left:-60px;
font-size:15px;
}

.wrap #block1 span{
left:10px;}

.wrap #block2 span,
.wrap #block3 span,
.wrap #block4 span {     
    left:-10px;

.block-row .wrap > img{position:relative; top:-30px;}
```

```html
<body>
<header>
  <div class="wrap">
    <img src="logo.png" alt="logo">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">CONTACT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="">SOFTWARE USED</a></li>
        <li><a href="">PROJECT</a></li>
        <li><a href="">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<section class="banner">
  <img src="building.png" alt="banner">
</section>

<h1>SOME ICONS</h1>
<section class="block-row">

<div class="wrap">
<div id="block1"> <img src="pers.png"><span> ABOUT </span> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. </p> </div>
<div id="block2"><img src="shield.png"> <span> COMPANY </span> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. </p></div>
<div id="block3"> <img src="cog.png"><span> SERVICES </span> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. </p></div>
<div id="block4"><img src="globe.png"><span> CONTACT </span>  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. </p></div>
</div>

</section>

</body>
```

Added this extra code. Change margin value according to your need.

```
.wrap #block1 img,
.wrap #block2 img,
.wrap #block3 img,
.wrap #block4 img {
  margin:40px;
}
```